# Do the Skaal believe in reincarnation or not?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

The Skaal are the only people with a clearly monotheistic faith I've encountered so far in Tamriel. However, I'm confused about their afterlife belief because of contradictory statements. Shaman Storn Crag-Strider says the following:

> "I also remind the Skaal to live as one with nature and to honor the will of the All-Maker, so that we'll be worthy to join him in death."

So according to Storn's statement it seems the Skaal believe in eternal life with God in Heaven. But when I read "Children of the All-Maker" I read the following statement:

> "When a creature dies, its spirit returns to the All-Maker, who shapes it into something new and returns it to Mundus."

The author, Tharstan of Solitude, told me he studied the Skaal almost a year now. In Morrowind Bloodmoon I so far never went far enough to have deep conversations with the Skaal, since Bloodmoon Skaal aren't as open-minded as described by Tharstan (I can only talk to the Skaal man whose son I have saved). Is there any clear final information on whether the Skaal believe in reincarnation or in eternal life in the hereafter?

Comment: I am doubtful if it is good to remove the specific tags. Shouldn't at least Skyrim-Dragonborn be included?

Comment: If your question is not specific to any game, as this seems to be, then it's more appropriate to use the tag for the series as a whole.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Well, it's specific about Skyrim Dragonborn and Morrowind Bloodmoon, but since there is no bloodmoon tag, it might be fine like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you take a closer look the statements aren't contradictory at all, in fact they tell the whole story.

The Shaman makes the statement of what to do to be worthy of joining the All-Maker when they die, but there's nothing being said about what happens after joining Him, so you can't conclude anything about eternal life, as it is not mentioned (if you do, that would be an assumption, which you actually assumed when you said it *seemed* that way).

The other statement actually talks about what happens after you die, i.e., after you *join the All-Maker*, by saying He re-shapes you and returns you back to Mundus.

So the first statement covers the path you have to take to be worthy and join the All-Maker, and the second one covers the next part, after joining Him you get to be shaped and sent back. **So to answer your question, yes they do (assuming those statements/sources to be true and reliable)**.

Comment: Well, "joining someone" is usually intended for a longer time, and here it could be understood as 'permanently', and Storn could have added what Tharstan wrote. If you're right then Tharstan expressed it in a better and more correct way than Storn.

Comment: You made me think and take a closer look to how both Storn and Tharstan said what they said; it seems like Storn is sharing (as in confidence with you) some part of his job. So maybe that explains why he wasn't so focused on telling the whole story. Tharstan, on the other hand, is a scholar with privileged close observation of the Skaal, and thus provides a clearer statement expected from someone documenting them. So I agree with you, Storn seems more vague and could have added what Tharstan said, but somehow Tharstan arrived at that conclusion and that is why I believe they're both correct.

Comment: On the other hand, Tharstan always praises how open-minded the Skaal are towards strangers, while from Morrowind Bloodmoon I get quite a different impression. Maybe Tharstan is just wrong or came to wrong conclusions, or rather doesn't write about a literal reincarnation but means that the All-Maker creates new life while the old one enters eternity in Heaven? Bloodmoon could shed light on this, but I haven't gone far enough in the Raven Rock quests and Fort Frostmoth quests.

Comment: I haven't played Morrowind myself, so i wouldn't know what Bloodmoon has on this. But, even checking the [fandom on the Skaal](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Skaal#Religion) they put the same story, and their source is literally the "Children of the All-Maker" from Tharstan. So having to rely on merely one source isn't that rigorous, and I agree with you. I acknowledge my answer was more a clarification and a conclusion based on those statements (assuming them to be true). Btw, thanks for keeping this interesting and keep being critical; perhaps I'll join you in looking in Bloodmoon.

Comment: The fandom's reference (source no. 4) links to Tharstan's "Children of the All-Maker", but they also seem to understand it as reincarnation. When you proceed in the East Empire Company Ravenrock quest, be careful in the Stalhrim quest if siding with Falco Galenus. It is bugged, read the uesp-wiki article on it before proceeding in the Stalhrim quest, the quest is what kept me from progressing.